# Does the geographical and beacon monitoring region add up for the 20 regions limit on iOS?

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon, clregion

I have read in the iOS documentation that we can monitor 20 regions. Does it mean that:
-the sum of both is limited to 20 
or 
-that I can have 20 geographical and 20 beacon regions
?

Comment: It would be helpful to add a link to the documentation you've read :)

Answer (score 0):

"*Be judicious when specifying the set of regions to monitor. Regions are a shared system resource, and the total number of regions available systemwide is limited. For this reason, Core Location limits to **20** the number of regions that may be simultaneously monitored by a single app.*"

Source : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Comment: I have read the documentation already... So you are saying that beacon region + geographical regions = 20 ?